# C#: proprietary DLLs requiring access to my assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005

My solution uses a proprietary assembly, which when debugging the solution throws an Exception saying it can't find an assembly that is meant to be one of the projects in my solution.

I cannot add a reference to the proprietary assembly because all I have is the DLL.

When I compile everything into a single application directory and run the app it works fine, but I want to debug.

Where should assemblies be placed if you want a proprietary assembly in the solution to see them?

I assume the issue is that there is no path specified and it is just looking in a default directory of some kind.

Comment: "I cannot add a reference to the proprietary assembly because all I have is the DLL" In .Net: DLL == assembly.

Comment: I'm with Foxfire, exactly why can't you add a reference to the DLL?  We use 3rd party assemblies all of the time...

Comment: I cannot add a reference to the 3rd party DLL.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(v=VS.100).aspx

Also search MSDN for AssemblyResolve, this will link you to additional articles to deepen your knowledge on this subject.

HTH!